# C - Extern struct

Tags: c++, c, string, struct, extern

I'm using structure to process NMEA messages, but I don't know what, something goes wrong when processing it. So, I have NMEA_parse.h:

```
/* GPRMC */
 #define TIME   2U
 #define LAT        4U
 #define LON        6U
 #define SPD        8U
 #define ANG        9U
 #define DATE   10U

extern struct gprmc{
    char time[10];
    char latitude[10];
    char longitude[10];
    char speed[10];
    char angle[10];
    char date[10];
}gprmc_datas;
```

NMEA_parse.c:

```
#include "NMEA_parse.h"

struct gprmc gprmc_datas;

static void fill_data (char* param_in)
{
    uint8_t i = 0U;             
    char* trunk;                
    char trunk_datas[20U][10U]; 

    trunk = strtok(param_in, ",");      
    while(trunk != NULL)
    {
        i++;        
        if(i > 20) { i = 0; }

        strcpy(trunk_datas[i],trunk);
        trunk = strtok (NULL, ",");     
    }

    if(memcmp(trunk_datas[1U],"GPRMC",6U) == 0U)
    {
        strcpy(gprmc_datas.time,trunk_datas[TIME]);
        strcpy(gprmc_datas.latitude,trunk_datas[LAT]);
        strcpy(gprmc_datas.longitude,trunk_datas[LON]);
        strcpy(gprmc_datas.date,trunk_datas[DATE]);
        strcpy(gprmc_datas.time,trunk_datas[TIME]);
    }
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "NMEA_parse.h"

int main(void)
{
    char *message = "$GPRMC,182127.00,A,4753.47678,N,02022.20259,E,0.837,,161019,,,A*7C\r\n";
    char *mes     = "$GPRMC,123519,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,230394,003.1,W*6A";
    proc_sentence(message);
    printf("\ntime: %s\n", gprmc_datas.time);
    printf("latitude: %s\n", gprmc_datas.latitude);
    printf("longitude: %s\n", gprmc_datas.longitude);
}
```

*proc_sentence* function pass the data to fill_data(), if the message valid (checksum, etc)
When I'm using the **mes** as input, everything is correct, but when I switch to **message**, some abnormality is shown, because the result is the following:

**time:** 182127.00

**latitude:** 4753.4767802022.2025E

**longitude:** 02022.2025E

Do you have any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: 4753.47678 is 10 chars, and you don't have extra byte for '\0' in your field.

Comment: `02022.20259` is 11 chars (not even counting the extra byte), so just flat out doesn't fit into an array of 10 chars. All of your arrays should be 64 bytes. And using `strtok` on a string literal causes undefined behavior. `char *message` and `char *mes` should be `char message[]` and `char mes[]`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't take into consideration the ending byte ('\0'). Increasing the storage for the array solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you change latitude[10] in the struct into latitude [12],  the string "message" can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike almost every other SO question about the use of scanf, yours is actually a problem that cries out for it.  After all, if a machine wrote it, a machine can read it, right?

Using C's concatenation of string literals, I got pretty close to filling the struct with a single function:

```
  int n = sscanf( message,
          "%[^,]," 
          "%[^,]," 
          "%*[^,],%[^,]," 
          "%*[^,],%[^,]," 
          "%*[^,],%[^,]," 
          "%[^,],"    
          "%[^,],", 
          label,
          gprmc.time, 
          gprmc.latitude, 
          gprmc.longitude, 
          gprmc.speed, 
          gprmc.angle, 
          gprmc.date );
```

This makes use of the little-used regex specifier, where we look for non-commas `%[^]` separated by commas.  The `%*[^]` specifies to skip the field.